# Why does Catboost outperform other boosting algorithms?

Tags: python, decision-trees, boosting, lightgbm, catboost

I have noticed while working with multiple datasets that catboost with its default parameters tends to outperform lightgbm or xgboost with its default parameters even on a tabular dataset with no categorical features.

I am assuming this has something to do with the way catboost constructs the decision trees but I just wanted to confirm this theory. If anyone could elaborate on why it performs better on non categorical data then that would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is a theorem that no algorithm can consistently outperform all other algorithms under all circumstances (no free lunch theorem), so most probably what you observe is simply coincidence

Answer (score 2):

There is no free lunch among `Catboost`, `XGBoost` and `LightGBM`. In my experience, some  cases I found that `XGBoost` outperform other, some cases for `LightGBM`, and the rest for `CatBoost`. So there is no exact the best model until you test them all in your dataset with doing hyper parameters tune to your model.
The only think clearly better from both `CatBoost` and `LightGBM` compare to `XGBoost` is only the way they deal with categorical features and faster fitting time.